# JavaScript and callback: apply an action on each element of a callback input

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm quite new to js. I even don't know how to call this problem: apply an action on each element of a callback input, but the elements are actually an output..

I crash a lot on this situation: I have a nested callback where first I load a json array and then I perform an action on each element of this array.

```
$.getJSON(DATA_URL+'/groups', function( groups ) {
    groups.forEach( function(g){
        appendDropdownItem(g);
    } );
});
```

I want to do it in one line. Not because I think one line is cool but because I think that this nested callback only gets the code dirty and affect readability.

In a pythonic approach I imagine somethings like a comprehension:

```
[appendDropDownItem(g) for g in loadAjax(DATA_URL+'/groups')]
```

So.. how to make it one liner/more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can realize that `function(x){return f(x)} == f`, so you can reduce one line there:

```
$.getJSON(DATA_URL +'/groups', function(groups){
  groups.forEach(appendDropdownItem)
})
```

It is harder to go further with these builtin functions. But if you have a curried `forEach`, with the arguments in the right order, such as the one in [Rambda](https://github.com/CrossEye/ramda), or in [Essentialjs](https://github.com/elclanrs/essential.js) (shameless plug), then you can reduce it even more:

```
$.getJSON(DATA_URL +'/groups', forEach(appendDropdownItem))
```

There you got a one readable one-liner.

You can implement your own curried `forEach` in any case:

```
var forEach = function(f) {
  return function(xs) {
    return xs.forEach(f)
  }
}
```

But these libraries include many other helpers that provide a more functional workflow that leads to these one-liners often by means of currying and composition.

Comment: nice! what about underscore?

Comment: underscore doesn't curry functions, and it has the arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: ok so in the end, which functional framework do you advice?

Comment: Well, I would recommend my own, linked above, but Rambda is more popular, but it is also bigger. If you're using Underscore you can always use partial application, like `_.partial(_.each, _, appendDropdownItem)`, but it looks quite ugly, and you'd have to do this with every function, since the arguments are backwards.